# What are the publisher's obligations when a research paper's term of copyright ends?

Tags: copyright, publishers

When a research paper's term of copyright ends, say, N years after publication, does the publication house **have to** make it freely (i.e. no cost) available for use by general public?  Assume that currently it's charging some money to download papers.

Comment: Guessing the motivation behind your question: If you (legally) want to obtain a copy of a paper, you might want to ask for ways to do this here (at least in a quick search I have not found that it has been asked yet).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft sorry I don't have that motivation. I am simply trying to think for the far future :)

Comment: There's no difference between research papers and any other copyrighted work.

Comment: What kind of obligations are you asking about?  Legal obligations?  Moral obligations?  If legal, in what jurisdiction, and what does the contract with the authors say?  The answer to your question is almost certainly going to be "no, of course not, not unless it made some promises to that extent -- why would it have any obligation?".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, why should it? Running out of copyright explicitly means a loss of a right. It does not mean the beginning of any additional obligation.

Running out of copyright, however, means that anybody who already owns a copy may duplicate it and make it available under any conditions he chooses (including making it available free of charge). Many university libraries do this.

Comment: `anybody who already owns a copy`, what if there is no one alive (outside the pub. house) who owns a copy (hypothetical scenario)? If someone then approaches the pub. house, are they obliged to provide it?

Comment: That does not change anything. They do not have an obligation to give you a copy. Actually, they do not even have to do so while they have the copyright.

Comment: @user19905 so that presents a dismal scenario hundred years down the line if a pub. house turns rogue/becomes defunct in future and no one has any copies!

Comment: @user13107: That’s one of the reasons, why [national libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_library) exist. Though, if a publisher was any good, there will be numerous libraries holding copies.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but not practically. Each scientific journal is subscribed to and archived by hundreds of libraries. A publication has to be extremely insignificant for libraries to not archive it. In that case, the publication probably deserves to be unobtainable.

Comment: @RobertBuchholz What about digital archives of publications? I suppose libraries don't have access to offline digital copies of all the papers. Do they? At uni. we download papers via going to publisher site and not from local library repository.

Comment: That's a slightly different situation. I suppose, libraries will not archive those digital subscriptions. However, in those cases the subscription is not based on "__delivery__ of X physical journals per years", but usually rather "__guaranteed access__ to all publications of type Y since year Z". In this case, the publisher has a __contractual obligation__ to give the subscribers access to the publication no matter what the copyright status.

Comment: @user13107 That is what systems like [LOCKSS](http://www.lockss.org/about/what-is-lockss/) (Lots Of Copies Keep Stuff Safe) are for: distributed digital archives. A significant fraction of university libraries and publishers are already participating, so that access to articles is not interrupted if a publisher goes under.

Comment: _the publisher has a contractual obligation to give the subscribers access to the publication no matter what the copyright status_ — ...until the library's subscription ends, or the publisher goes out of business.  (In contrast, libraries can keep copies of paper journals after their publishers die.)

Comment: @JeffE: I believe some subscription contracts provide for perpetual digital access to anything published during (or even before) the subscription term, even if the subscription is later cancelled. That addresses your first point. I understand that in some such deals, the library gets their own digital copy of the entire archive, addressing your second point.

Comment: _I believe some subscription contracts provide for perpetual digital access_ — I'm not aware of any such contracts, at least with major publishers like Elsevier or Springer.  But maybe things have changed since the last time I looked into it.